# Angularjs directive controller : wait for DOM to be ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, d3.js

I'm writing a lineChart directive which loads data from a given url :

```
<line-chart dataurl="{{ some_url }}"></line-chart>
```

Then in my lineChart directive, I have a controller which is supposed to load data :

```
directive('lineChart', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'EA',
          scope: {
              dataurl: '@'
          },
          controller: function($scope, $http){

            $http.get($scope.dataurl)
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.data = data;
                });
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              ...
```

The problem here is that the controller is called before the DOM is ready, which means that dataurl="" and I get a 404 error. I imagine there is a solution to that using the $timeout service, but I don't need the whole DOM to be ready, only the `<line-chart>` part. 
How could I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use the ng-attr-* directive instead to let angular construct the real attribute at the right time :

```
<line-chart ng-attr-dataurl="some_url"></line-chart>
```

cf. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

edit: note that you'll need a `$scope.some_url` var in your controller

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. When I `console.log($scope.dataurl)` in my directive controller, I have an empty string even with the ng-attr- attribute.

Maybe I could avoid using a controller and instaead write a `$watch.(dataurl)` in the directive link part, do nothing if it's empty and load data if it's not, but it's not very elegant...

Comment: Yeah sorry I edited my post, remove the brackets. Try posting a jsfiddle if it doesn't work either

Comment: Actually I think I need the brackets since some_url depends on a variable called topicId.
Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zRxj8/5/ but it won't really work because I'm not sure how to handle d3 dependencies and XHR calls

Comment: Try creating a (not) working jsfiddle underlining only our concern here